# error in inserting in vector of set

Tags: c++

I am getting the error: "expected initializer before 'a'" in the following piece of code. But I am not getting what is the use of the initializer and how should I put one. I am a beginner in C++ so please excuse my novice question.

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 vector<set<unsigned> > a;
 set<unsigned>::iterator it;
 a[0].insert(0);
 a[0].insert(1);
 a[0].insert(2);
 for(it=a[0].begin(); it!=a[0].end; ++it)
 {
  cout<<*it;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code as shown in the question (if it compiled) will cause undefined behaviour, as you don't add anything to the vector, but still access the first element as there was one.

Comment: Note that this is undefined behavior (even if it were to compile). `a` is empty, so `a[0]` is undefined behavior. You should either set `a`'s size to one by doing `a(1);` when you construct it, or by using `a.push_back(...)` after constructing `a`.

Comment: I noticed you silently fixed the problems that were shown to you in the answers.  But you can't be still getting that same error.  Now your only remaining (compile time) error, is the lack of parens on `a[0].end`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks +1 to u...it fixed my error

Comment: @Cornstalks Thanks +1 to u...it fixed my error

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ya I just corrected the typo...I hope thats ok

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste your code directly from your editor, exactly as you compiled, or tried to compile it.  That way, nobody wastes their time pointing out errors which aren't actually there.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem (or at least one problem) is a missing semicolon:

```
set<unsigned>::iterator it
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not `using namespace std` then you must prefix the members of that namespace with `std::`:

```
std::vector<std::set<unsigned> > a;
```